# Not able to make Call on iOS 7.1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to make call from application. For that I have used following code:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:strCareProviderPhone];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

For iOS 7.1.1 and iOS 8.0 its working fine. For iOS 7.1.2, its not working. For iOS 7.1.2 the phone number formatting is (999) 9900000. 
PS: I have also tried using string formatting like stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString for bracket and space. But NO success.

Can any one please help me into this.

Thanks in advance,

Akshay

Comment: out of curiosity what happens on iOS 7.1.2 if you use `telprompt://` instead?

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin I agree with you, I think it makes sense to use ```telprompt://``` instead anyway, as it redirects the user back to your app after the call has been finished.

Comment: telprompt:// is also not working.. I really don't understand what is going wrong ? Is it some kind of bug present in iOS 7.1.2 ?